# Java scanner input if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

This line does not work: `input=scan.nextLine();`

You should give the program the input for the while loop, but it ignores completely this line. I don't know the problem and I am just a beginner. Could you help?

```
import java.util.*;


public class Fantasy2
{

  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
    String name;
    String input="y";
    int strength;
    int health;
    int luck;
    int stats;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of your character:");
    name=scan.nextLine();

    while(input.equals("y"))
    {
    System.out.println("Strength (1-10):");
    strength=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Health (1-10):");
    health=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Luck (1-10):");
    luck=scan.nextInt();
    stats=strength+health+luck;

    if(stats>15)
        {
        System.out.println("You gave your character too much points! Do you want to change that?");
        input=scan.nextLine();
        } 
    else
        {
        System.out.println(name + " has these stats now: Strength:" + strength + ", Health: " + health + ", Luck: " + luck);
        input="n";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Congratulation! You created successful your character!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. This clearly looks like homework which is not an issue if you show us what you have tried so far. Whats the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the statement posted below does not help your original problem but is another problem the line `input = scan.nextLine();` works for me fine.

When using `Scanner` you must call another `scan.nextLine();` after you `scan.nextInt();` to get the line feed that the method `scan.nextInt();` does not get

do this

```
System.out.println("Strength (1-10):");
strength=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Health (1-10):");
health=scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Luck (1-10):");
luck=scan.nextInt();
stats=strength+health+luck;
scan.nextLine();    <--------- added code
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to consume the extra new line that `nextInt` does not consume. Your options are to call another `newLine` after the last call to `nextInt` or better yet, read the integer input through `nextLine` and parse it:

```
private int readInteger()
{
   int option = 0;
   try 
   {
      option = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
   } 
   catch (NumberFormatException e) 
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return option;
}

...
System.out.println("Strength (1-10):");
strength = readInteger();
System.out.println("Health (1-10):");
health = readInteger();
System.out.println("Luck (1-10):");
luck = readInteger();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code instead of your while cycle:

```
    boolean flag=true;
    while(flag)
    {
    System.out.println("Strength (1-10):");
    int strength=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Health (1-10):");
    int health=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Luck (1-10):");
    int luck=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    int stats=strength+health+luck;

    if(stats>15)
        {
        System.out.println("You gave your character too much points! Do you want to change that?");
        input=scan.nextLine();
        } 
    else
        {
        System.out.println("has these stats now: Strength:" + strength + ", Health: " + health + ", Luck: " + luck);
        input="n";
        }

    if(input.equals("n"))
        flag = false;

    }


    System.out.println("Congratulation! You created successful your character!");
```

I don't know if this is a better way of doing it but give it a try.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the Scanner

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and the methods ( read [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for detail)

`next()` - would read next characters until it found space ( or the delimiter used. by default space) and return String.

`nextInt()` - would read next characters until it found space ( or the delimiter used. by default space) and convert it into int and return.

Note** if you give input as 'xyz' you will get exception and your program would terminate.

if you give 5   7  for answer `(Strength (1-10):)` as per your program it would read 5 as strength and 7 as health. and will ask for luck.

`nextLine()` would read all characters until the end of line found ( while you enter in keyboard).

So the ideal implementation to avoid issues .

You can use nextLine and convert into int if not say as error and ask to enter correct value.

```
System.out.println("Strength (1-10):");
            String str=scan.nextLine();
            while (!isNumeric(str)){
                System.out.println("Enter Valid Number Strength (1-10):");
                str=scan.nextLine();
            }
            strength = Integer.parseInt(str);

 public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
        {
            return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
        }
```

For example , when you call  `luck=scan.nextInt();`  users enters 6 and enter key . 6 will capture by `nextInt()` and the enter key would capture by   `input=scan.nextLine();` . 
So in order to get next input you have to ask `scan.nextLIne()` again  like

```
 luck=scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLIne();
```